# Использование оригинального AsyncTask с LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, android-asynctask

Я хочу использовать `AsyncTask` из пакета `android.os`. Да, я знаю, что есть собственный `AsyncTask` из пакета `com.badlogic.utils`, но мне нужен именно первый. Таким образом, я импортировал это:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
```

Используемое SDK: `Android 20 API Platform.`

И когда я запускаю, я получаю ошибки:

```
Error:(4, 18) error: package android.os does not exist
Error:(146, 38) error: cannot find symbol class AsyncTask
Error:(30, 26) error: cannot find symbol method execute()
Error:(148, 9) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

И это касается не только AsyncTask, я так и не нашёл адекватного объяснения каким образом можно использовать "родные" для Android классы. Признателен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, нет возможности получить доступ к Android API из модуля core. Этот модуль используется для всех платформ.

Но есть способ это обойти - при помощи [интерфейсов](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) можно получить доступ к возможностям платформы.